# Inserting a new line into a PHP file via the CLI

Tags: command-line, bash, php-cli

**Goal:** Insert a new line into a PHP file via CommandLine.

**Problem:** I have a PHP file with an array. I want to append a new value (`hello folks`) to this PHP array using a bash script.

**Starting point:**

```php
<?php

return [
    'line 1',
    'line 2',
    'line 3',
];
```

**Expected result:**

```php
<?php

return [
    'line 1',
    'line 2',
    'line 3',
    'hello folks',
];
```

**Question:** Which CLI command can I use under ubuntu?

Comment: This seems like either a homework question, or a security vulnerability in sheep's clothing ... 

Comment: @matigo You are right! I make homework for sheeps in clothings :-) Joking aside. Neither. I'm just getting into PHP Symfony and when you use composer to install libs, configuration files are edited in the background. And I wonder how that works. That' s why I'm asking.

Comment: Sounds like a good reason for me to avoid Symfony. I generally hand-write all of my code because ... I'm old. Rant aside, [this U&L answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/369819/471157) should give you the gist. If you know the location of the array and the `]` of that array is always the first to appear in the file, then this solution would be one way to do it.

Comment: Thank you very much @matigo for the link. 

Answer (score 0):

sed command is available on all unix by default

So you can try this:

```
sed -i '/line 3/a\'\''hello folks'\'',' yourfile.php
```

Explaination:

**-i** : Make changes into the file insted of STDOUT

**line 3** : Pattern to search

**/a** : Add a line after the matched pattern

**\''hello folks'\'',** : Pattern to add with single quote escaped

Comment: i will try and give you a feedback. Thank you Angel115

Comment: It's a little twist, but it works ;-)

Comment: Thank you for you answer! I tried your code and unfortunately it is not working for me. I got the error message: undefined label phpfilename.php

Comment: This usualy happen on Mac OSx and not on ubuntu. But in this case try by adding 2 double quote just after the -i, like this **sed -i "" '/line 3/a\'\''hello folks'\'',' yourfile.php**

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed '/line 3/{p;s/[a-z]\+ [0-9]/hello folks/}' input_file
<?php

return [
    'line 1',
    'line 2',
    'line 3',
    'hello folks',
];
```

Comment: thank your for answer. But got this message:  `bad flag in substitute command: '}'